# How to use ChangeTokenStart and ChangeTokenEnd with a Rest API in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to retrieve a list of Items for a particular list between two change tokens using Rest Apis.I am using chrome rest api client.

My rest endpoint looks like this ->

```
    Method: POST
    Headers:
    Authorization: bearer <Access token value>
    Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
    Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose

    Body:
    metadata type:'SP.ChangeQuery',
    Add: 'true',
    Update: 'true',
    Item: 'true',
    ChangeTokenStart:'start token string value'
```

I am getting following error:

```
    value: "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected."
```

Questions:
1) Do we need to use some other method instead of getChanges in `enter code here`conjunction with ChangeTokenStart and ChangeTokenEnd methods?

2) What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this post (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx#bk_ListGetChanges). As you can see from response, ChangeToken is not primitive type but complex. Try to construct the same complex type as you can see in the response in example.

Comment: I tried doing that but may be I am messing up with the syntax part of it. I am somehow not getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get the values of {ChangeTime} and {ChangeNumber} to send? I receive a notification (from a subscription to a SP list) that the following changes have occurred:

```
"value":[
    {
      "subscriptionId":"956f4000-93ba-4e36-baf5-310d7e99b11d",
      "clientState":"TwoWayFunctionApp",
      "expirationDateTime":"2017-06-01T16:17:57.000Z",
      "resource":"fce41000-8cc9-46b9-a534-e9a3dce84739",
      "tenantId":"fabef000-b0bb-4156-b901-410a36ad78b0",
      "siteUrl":"/sites/Development",
      "webId":"302c4000-e688-408a-94b7-476f17e6fbd5"
    }
]}
```

(Assume subscription Id is the {Guid} to send)

If you leave the ChangeTokenStart and ChangeTokenEnd as null, what changes do you get? e.g. ALL changes made EVER?!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should make the post data

{ 'query': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' },'Web': true, 'Update': true, 'Add': true,'ChangeTokenStart':{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.ChangeToken'}, 'StringValue':'blabla'}}}

If you look at the properties of  [ChangeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245254(v=office.15).aspx), you'll find "ChangeTokenStart" and "ChangeTokenEnd" and both of these are complex objects, so that's the way you should send the query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint REST endpoint expects `Change Token` value to be provided in the following format:

```
"ChangeTokenProperty": { "StringValue" : "Version;Scope;Guid;ChangeTime;ChangeNumber" }
```

Assume the following function is used for getting changes from a Change Log:

```
function getChanges(webUrl,queryOptions,success,failure)
{
   var changeQueryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' },  
        } 
   };
   for(var key in queryOptions) {
       changeQueryPayload['query'][key] = queryOptions[key];
   }

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(changeQueryPayload),
      url: webUrl + '/_api/web/getchanges', 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}
```

Then, the following example demonstrates how to specify ChangeToken value:

```
var queryOptions = {"Update":true,"Web": true, "ChangeTokenStart": { "StringValue" : "1;2;6dfea1bb-6a93-4d49-a8cd-7e797716a8e5;635427410784300000;23922265" }};


getChanges(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,queryOptions,
  function(result){
      var changes = result.d.results;
      //print info
      console.log('Found ' + changes.length + ' items');   
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
```

### About Change Token

According to [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/12/04/content-deployment-the-complete-guide-part-7-change-token-basics.aspx) Change Token has the following format:

```
{Version};{Scope};{Guid};{ChangeTime};{ChangeNumber}
```

Comment: What should be the value of ChangeNumber for the first time?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar -1 is the initial value for ChangeNumber.